# "No spool was specified" error while running migrated pipelines via Azure DevOps Migration tool

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-migration-tools, azure-migrate

We recently migrated our Pipelines to different Org using Azure DevOps Migration Tool. The Migration itself was successful and we can see all the migrated pipeline in Destination project.
But encounter an error "No spool was specified" while running the migrated pipelines.

Does anyone face this issue with the Azure DevOps Migration tool?

I tried by creating a new pipeline in Destination project to check its working and it worked with no issues.

The issue getting only with the migrated pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

> Encounter an error "No pool was specified" while running the migrated pipelines

Based on the error message, it seems that the migrated pipelines no agent specified。

You can edit the migrated pipelines and check the agent pool.

[image]

Then you can save the pipeline and run again.

**Update:**

For Yaml Pipeline, you can navigate to **Edit Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers ->  YAML -> Pipeline -> Default agent pool for YAML**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see the exact screen when doing the EDIT pipeline. I see the YAML code.
The above attached screenshot i see when i create a new pipeline using classic editor.

But under Project Settings-->Agent Pools  , i can see that my migrated pipelines trying to run against Azure Pipeline Agent but throwing No pool was specified error

Comment: @stackuser Please check my update about YAML pipeline. You can share the result with me

Comment: Thanks Kevin.. Yes i can see the option now and it solved my problem too.

Comment: Kevin..
I have successfully migrated 100's of pipeline via azure migration tool but  somehow the Agent pool is not set to Azure Pipeline automatically.
I have to follow your steps manually for each one of them in order to get  my migrated pipeline work.

Wondering , is there any settings in migration tool OR any other automatic way where i can set up the Agent pool all at once rather than going one by one ?

Comment: @stackuser Consider going to this issue on the feedback hub and commenting on the "solution" to let Microsoft know we'd like this fixed. We shouldn't have to do a workaround.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Auto-created-pipeline-from-yaml-return-e/10054547?q=yaml+no+pool+was+specified